# How to simplify CustomKeywords calls?

Tags: methods, groovy, katalon-studio

There is a way to simplified CustomKeywords calls into Test case?

Indeed, use `CustomKeywords.'package.class.method'(param1, param2)` everytime is not ideal.

So I'm looking to find a way to do something like :

```
line 1 : CustomKeywords.package.class as EasyCall
line W : ...
line X : def result = EasyCall.method(param1, param2)
line Y : ...
line Z : def result2 = EasyCall.method(param1, param2)
```

instead of

```
line W : ...
line X : def result = CustomKeywords.'package.class.method'(param1, param2)
line Y : ...
line Z : def result2 = CustomKeywords.'package.class.method'(param1, param2)
```

Does someone have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Custom Keyword" in Katalon is just a plain old method. So, everything you might do in Groovy or Java applies here as well.

So, to simplify method calls, you need to import

```
import package.class as EasyCall
```

and your method inside of the `package` needs to be **static**:

```
package package

@Keyword
def static method1(param1, param2){
    // body of method1
}
```

Then you simply call the method within your test script with:

```
EasyCall.method1(param1, param2)
```